# Ansible loop returns outputs entire object

Tags: ansible

I am gathering information about AWS ec2 instances and then attempting to loop through them to output the instance_id property of the registered results.

When I run through the loop I get the expected results, but I also get the entire registered object outputted as well. It appears to flatten the object to a string and output it. What is the reason for the additional output and is there a better loop method I should use?

Thank you in advance!

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: get ec2 instance info
      ec2_instance_info:
        region: us-east-1
        filters:
          "tag:app": ansible
          "tag:env": dev
      register: ec2

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item['instance_id'] }}"
      loop: "{{ ec2['instances'] }}"
```

[image: extra output]

**FIX**

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item['instance_id'] }}"
  loop: "{{ ec2['instances'] }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.instance_id }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your answer @duffney.

By the looks of things Was addressed as a bug/feature and amended

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/35493
Does it help out what you are looking for?

Comment: Confirmed! That was the fix. Adding the loop_control was what I needed. Thank you!

 loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.instance_id }}"